# How does the implementation of list in F# work?

Tags: f#

I'm curious as to how the list module/type works in F#, specifically does it optimise this?

```
let xs = ["1"; "2"; "3"]

let ys = "0"::xs

let zs = ["hello"; "world"]@xs
```

I've looked over some of the source https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/68e37d03dfc15f8105aeb0ac70b846f82b364901/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3493 seems to be the relevant area.

I would like to know if `xs` is copied when making `ys`.

I would have thought it's easy to just point to the existing list if you just cons element.

If you are concatenating I imagine it might be impossible as it would require mutating the last element of the list to point to the next one?

If someone could annotate/paste snippets of code from FSharp.Core that would be ideal.

Comment: When creating `ys` `xs` isn't deep copied (That's one of the benefits of immutable single linked lists)

Comment: Do you know where I could find any info on this specific to F#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So the implementation of List is a little odd.  It is actually implemented as a discriminated union.  From the spec:

```
type 'T list =
| ([])  
| (::)  of 'T * 'T list
```

So you can think of `::` as a function that takes two arguments and creates a tuple (which is fast as it is independent of the list size).

`@` is much more complicated.  Here is the implementation:

```
    let (@) l1 l2 = 
        match l1 with
        | [] -> l2
        | (h::t) -> 
        match l2 with
        | [] -> l1
        | _ -> 
          let res = [h] 
          let lastCons = PrivateListHelpers.appendToFreshConsTail res t 
          PrivateListHelpers.setFreshConsTail lastCons l2;
          res
```

The two weird functions basically mutate the list in place.  `appendToFreshConsTail` copies the list and returns the last element.  `setFreshConsTail` then changes the last element so that its next element is set to `l2` rather than `[]` joining the lists.

Comment: That last paragraph was what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!